# Electric central door lock does not work with automatic transmission shifting to and from “Park”

Tags: toyota, locks, door, corolla

My 2004 Toyota Corolla S does not lock or open the central door lock when moving from/to “Park”. The manual and remote works just fine.  It is only with the automatic transmission that when I move to “Park”, it does not release the lock and doesn’t lock when I move from “Park” to “Drive”.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if your door lock sequence mode got changed. [change-door-lock-sequence](http://www.ehow.com/how_5640027_change-door-lock-sequence-toyota.html)