# Auto door lock does not work with automatic transmission shifting to and from “Park”

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, corolla, door, central-locking

My Toyota Corolla 2014 Altis auto door lock has not been worked.

I read [Electric central door lock does not work with automatic transmission shifting to and from “Park”](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3438/electric-central-door-lock-does-not-work-with-automatic-transmission-shifting-to) and also [Toyota Corolla Owners Manual: Automatic door locking and unlocking systems](http://www.tcorolla.net/automatic_door_locking_and_unlocking_systems-60.html). I follow the instruction in the user manual, However, I couldn't set this option on my cars anyways.

I found [Automatic Door Lock Closing CANBUS OBD system suitable For New Vios Corolla](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Automatic-Door-Lock-Closing-CANBUS-OBD-system-For-TOYOTA-New-Vios-Corolla-RAV4-Car-speed-lock/701329_607485835.html) and [Toyota Auto Door Lock OBD](http://www.pakwheels.com/accessories/toyota-auto-door-lock-obd-2-priusaquavitz-grandealtis-1490296) but I'm not sure that is compatible with my car and it's very hard to buy those `OBD`.

**Edit1:**

---

**Note:** The central door lock works correctly with remote key and also with driver's door lock switch.
My car's gearbox is `AT`.

**Edit2:**

---

Ok, according to @Ben Answer I research for configuring the `Auto Door Lock` on the ECU. So after I googled I found these videos:

1. [How To Use Toyota Techstream Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbFo04_67pQ).
2. [Toyota Techstream Software Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDpldAv0uQE).

So I understand that I can do this with [Global Tech Stream (GTS) software](https://www.toyota-tech.eu/GTS/Wizard/Step5-Software.aspx) and the cable that named [MINI-VCI J2534](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D6BA082).

**Question:** I'd like to modify the ECU settings. Is it a risky work? What's the difference between the original and fake MINI-VCI J2534 (I saw this video too [Disassembly of the fake mini VCI cable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0E7tBXDkexY), however, I didn't understand what's its means)?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you saying you think your car has this feature but it doesn't work, or that it doesn't have it and you want it?

Comment: According to user manual, my car must have this feature, However, I think that this feature is disable or may be my car doesn't have this feature at all. Anyway, I'd like to have this feature even if I must design a device to do it.

Comment: The power door locks operate normally otherwise?

Comment: @Ben, Yes. The central door lock works correctly with remote key and also with driver's door lock switch.

Comment: and to make sure this is an automatic or cvt trans?

Comment: @Ben, this is an `AT` gearbox.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the only option other than an aftermarket system would be to goto a Toyota dealer or a independent shop with the Toyota TechStream Software and to enable this feature.

It looks like this option should be on by default but was never setup or was disabled for some reason.

Edit:

It looks you may be able to do this from the Multi-Display.

SET UP / Vehicle / Vehicle Customization / Other vehicle settings..

Comment: My car doesn't have `Multi-Display`.

Comment: Hmm, that last bit would've been my only suggestion. I'm not familiar with the Altis line but I have a 14 LE that has this setting buried away in the main console settings. Odd that this isn't working, because every Toyota I've driven has had this by default. Did you purchase the car used? EDIT: oops, just realized the age of this post. Any luck so far? @Tom

Comment: @sheng Jul, It didn't used car, it was the brand new car. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tom If you don't have any sort of center console with a settings menu I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. At this stage, the next best thing may be to kick it. You just never know these days. (Would talk to your local dealer if you haven't already.)